# Default parameters and forward declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, default-arguments

I have a class `Property` with a constructor in which I want default parameters, in a file `property.h`:

```
class Property {
  Property(OtherClass* value = myApp->someValue) {...};
};
```

where `myApp`, of another type `Application`, is defined in another file that makes extensive use of this Property class. Since this other file #includes property.h, of course, I cannot #include this file in property.h

`property.h` does not know about `myApp` nor `Application` (though `property.cpp` does, and `OtherClass` is known in `property.h`).
I could forward declare `OtherClass` and declare `myApp` as `extern`, but this results in an error C2027 "use of undefined type Application", as expected :

```
class Application;
extern Application* myApp;
class Property {
  Property(OtherClass* value = myApp->someValue) {...};
};
```

A solution could be to have the default parameter in the .cpp file, but this is not advisable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902129/default-parameters-in-h-and-cpp-files)).

How can I get this default parameter working ? (i.e., not another solution that would  involve not having default parameters telling me default parameters are evil, or that my design is poor to start with etc. ;) ). Thanks!

Comment: Most problems can be solved by yet another level of indirect. Make a function call which is implemented in the `.cc` where `Application` is known. (Try to make an MCVE to check it out...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remarkable point is that the default argument of function parameters is resolved where the function is called (in opposition to where the function is defined). That gives the necessary space to solve OPs problem by [yet another level of indirection](https://wiki.c2.com/?OneMoreLevelOfIndirection):

Instead of accessing `myApp->someValue`, a helper function is introduced, which can be declared before the definition of `Property` but implemented after `Application` is fully defined. (This could be a `static` member function of `Property` as well.)

An example to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>

int getAppDefault();

struct Application;
extern Application *pApp;

struct Property {
  int value;
  Property(int value = getAppDefault()): value(value) { }
};

struct Application {
  int valueDefault = 123;
};

Application app;
Application *pApp = &app;

int getAppDefault() { return pApp->valueDefault; }

int main()
{
  Property prop1;
  std::cout << "prop1: " << prop1.value << '\n';
  app.valueDefault = 234;
  Property prop2;
  std::cout << "prop2: " << prop2.value << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
prop1: 123
prop2: 234
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d7c575e530c59cf)

To emphasize that `value = getAppDefault()` is in fact resolved when the constructor `Property::Property()` is called, I modified the `Application::valueDefault` before default-constructing `prop2`.

---

And, of course, this works as well if the `Property` stores a pointer instead of the value itself:

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c254fa29e9f8a42)

Comment: I'm validating this answer although I ended up using a simpler option (defaulting to NULL, and then in the constructor moved to the cpp file, testing for NULL and using myApp->someValue instead). But the other option to have another empty constructor would not have worked so easily in my case as I have other parameters with default values that come before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to use a member of the `Application` class you *must* have the full definition of the `Application` class. Otherwise the compiler will not know about the members of the class.

Secondly, you should probably make the `Property` constructor `explicit` to inhibit implicit conversions from `Application`. Such implicit conversion tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Thirdly, and as a possible way to work around the first problem, you could use *overloading* to have two `Property` constructors: One with a non-default `Property*` argument, and one without any argument at all. The argument-less constructor delegates to the one-argument constructor for initialization. This split into two constructor function will make it easier to define (implement) separate from declaration.

---

In code my solution would look something like this:

First the `Property` header file

```
// Forward declaration only, no header file needed
class OtherClass;

class Property
{
public:
    Property();
    explicit Property(OtherClass* other);

    // ...
};
```

Then the `Property` class *source* file

```
#include "Property.h"

// Get the full and complete definition of the Application class
#include "Application.h"

extern Application* myApp;

// Will probably need the full definition of the OtherClass as well
#include "OtherClass.h"

// Default constructor delegates to one-argument constructor
Property::Property()
    : Property{ myApp->GetOtherObject() }
{
}

Property::Property(OtherClass* other)
{
    // Use the other class here...
}
```